# Laptop Synaptics Touchpad No Longer Functional After Windows 7 Upgrade

Tags: windows-7, synaptics-touchpad

I have a Toshiba laptop, with an integral Synaptics (PS/2 port) touch pad, that I bought pre-installed with 32-bit Windows Vista.  After doing a clean install of 32-bit Windows 7, I can no longer get the touch pad to respond.

The function (FN) keys on the laptop still operate correctly, but they no longer display on screen when used.  I have no way of knowing if the function key to enable / disable the touch pad is working correctly, although the function keys for dim / brighten display, as well as others, work fine.

I have removed the device from the device manager and allowed it to reinstall with no success.  I have removed the previous drivers and updated them with the current 32-bit Win7 compatible versions from Synaptics website, with no success.  The Synaptics icon displays in the taskbar, and the touch pad is available in the Device Manager, both of which say the device is installed and working correctly.  I have checked to make sure that the touch pad is enabled in the Synaptics menu, and have tried toggling enabled / disabled with no success.

If anyone has any suggestions, or knows where I can find a solution, I would be very appreciative.

Comment: The Synaptics driver comes with two "accessories" (Moodpad and pressure-graph).  Do they show the activity when you press on the pad?

Comment: driver driver driver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you install drivers from Toshiba's website? Or did you let Windows 7 automatically install the drivers?

If you didn't install the drivers from Toshiba's website that could be your problem.  To get the FN keys working you need to install the Toshiba Value Added Pack.  That could fix your touch pad also because your touch pad could just be off but since your FN keys doesn't work properly it doesn't let you turn it on.  If the Value Added Pack doesn't solve the touchpad issue download and install the Synaptic drivers from Toshiba's website.